# NetSuite Webstore Correlated Items

Tags: e-commerce, netsuite, webstore

[image]

Hi!

Does anyone know how to add items on the Correlated items under webstore in the item records in NetSuite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot add items to this list manually.  They are added by the NetSuite system automatically based on orders in the system and how often items are purchased together.  To manually add upsell items, you can use the Related Items list instead, where you *can* manually add whatever items you want.  To do this, go into Edit mode on the item record, navigate to Web Store > Related Items and you can enter the item name/number that you want in the list area.

See SuiteAnswer [35466](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/35466/kw/correlated%20items%20calculation) for more information on related and correlated items.